# How to properly import a library (?) in Python

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I've been trying to use the tldextract library available here.

After many attempts, I was able to get it installed. However, now when it comes to run the main file, the compiler says that it can't find any reference to my library. Below the code I used and that raise the exception.

```
import tldextract
```

I appreciate this is a very basilar question and it is not totally connected with the library I'm trying to use, but I wonder if you can point me in the direction on how to "link" or make sure the compiler know that I have that library.

As far as I can understand as long a library is avaialble in the site-packages folder, this should sort the problem.

In my circumstance the file is at

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract

So in theory this should be ok, but I get the following error when I try to use it.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
  import tldexport
ImportError: No module named tldexport
```

I hope this question doesn't make you upset for it's simplicity. I'm here to learn after all.

Thanks

Comment: So tldexport or tldextract?

Comment: In case it isn't the obvious typo, the next most obvious possibility is that you may have two (or more) Python 2.7 installations. This is very common for Mac users, because of all the blog posts out there that tell you to install a second Python alongside the one Apple already gave you. If you do this, it's very easy to install a module for one copy of Python, then try to use it with the other copy. (For example, you `sudo pip install tldextract`, your `/usr/local/bin/pip` comes from the extra Python 2.7, and your `/usr/bin/python` comes from the Apple-installed Python 2.7.)

Comment: Pavel, you are absolutely right. It was a fault of mine. Importing the right library it works :( Apologies for the silly ticket guys. But very helpful insights as at least I learnt something new.

Comment: The whole question comes from a very specific typo the OP wrote in his program. (before this would have been a 'too localized')  

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error code, file test.py is calling a module named 'tldexport'

If that's a dependency, install it.

If it's a typo intended to be **tldextract**, then change it :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was a fault of mine. Importing the right library it works :( Apologies for the silly ticket guys. But very helpful insights as at least I learnt something new.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs on the Python import system](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) are nice. You should check them out. I recommend reading the **entire thing**. You'll be happy you did and most of your frustration regarding imports will be resolved. Like @Dreadful_Code says either correct the typo or change it. If `'tldexport' in sys.path` is `True` then things should go swimmingly; same goes for `tldextract` or really any Python module that you'd like to use from inside the interpreter.